# Writing data from a linked list to a txt file in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I created this program that first asks how many pets you own, then stores the name and age of each pet in a struct (all using linked lists).

My question is: I'm trying to write the data into a .txt file using a procedure `writeToFile()` but upon execution, the .txt file does not contain any data. I don't understand why?

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    char *name;
    int age;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Node * petRecord;
struct Node * newRecord;

void printPetRecord()
{  
    while(petRecord != NULL)
    {
        printf("Name of Pet: %s\n", petRecord->name);
        printf("Age of Pet: %d\n", petRecord->age);
        petRecord = petRecord->next;
    }
}

void writeToFile()
{
    FILE * fptr;
    fptr = fopen("petnames.txt", "w");

    if(fptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
    }

    else
    {
        while(petRecord != NULL)
        {
            fprintf(fptr, "\nPet Name: %s\nAge: %d\n", petRecord->name, petRecord->age);
            petRecord = petRecord->next;
        }
    }

    fclose(fptr);
    }

int main()
{ 
    int count, i;
    printf("How many pets do you have? ");
    scanf("%d", &count);

    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            petRecord = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            newRecord = petRecord;
        }
        else
        {
            newRecord->next = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            newRecord = newRecord->next;
        }
        newRecord->name = malloc(50*sizeof(char));
        printf("Name of Pet: ");
        scanf("%s", newRecord->name);
        printf("Age of Pet: ");
        scanf("%d", &newRecord->age);
    }
    newRecord->next = NULL;
    printf("\n\n");
    printPetRecord();
    writeToFile();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to print it on the standard output instead?

Comment: Don't use global variables.

Comment: @Katrina: you have lost your list head when you iterate directly with global variable

Answer (score 3):

Your function printPetRecord() leaves your pointer set to null.

Inside printPetRecord() make something like this:

```
struct Node * iterator = petRecord;
```

and then itertae using iterator.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    char *name;
    int age;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Node * petRecord;
struct Node * newRecord;

void printPetRecord()
{
    struct Node * iterator = petRecord;
    while(iterator != NULL)
    {
        printf("Name of Pet: %s\n", iterator->name);
        printf("Age of Pet: %d\n", iterator->age);
        iterator=iterator->next;
    }
}

void writeToFile()
{
    FILE * fptr;
    fptr = fopen("petnames.txt", "w");
    struct Node * iterator = petRecord;

    if(fptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
    }

    else
    {
        while(iterator!= NULL)
        {
            fprintf(fptr, "\nPet Name: %s\nAge: %d\n", iterator->name, iterator->age);
            iterator= iterator->next;
        }
    }

    fclose(fptr);
    }

int main()
{
    int count, i;
    printf("How many pets do you have? ");
    scanf("%d", &count);

    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            petRecord = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            newRecord = petRecord;
        }
        else
        {
            newRecord->next = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            newRecord = newRecord->next;
        }
        newRecord->name = malloc(50*sizeof(char));
        printf("Name of Pet: ");
        scanf("%s", newRecord->name);
        printf("Age of Pet: ");
        scanf("%d", &newRecord->age);
    }
    newRecord->next = NULL;
    printf("\n\n");
    printPetRecord();
    writeToFile();
}
```

Execution:

```
> gcc -o main main.c
> ./main
How many pets do you have? 2
Name of Pet: a
Age of Pet: 2
Name of Pet: b
Age of Pet: 3


Name of Pet: a
Age of Pet: 2
Name of Pet: b
Age of Pet: 3
> cat petnames.txt

Pet Name: a
Age: 2

Pet Name: b
Age: 3
```

Comment: That shows once again that global variables are evil.

Comment: By doing this [struct Node * iterator = petRecord], I create a new Node that points to the address of the first value of my linked list. So to write the data to the txt file, would I do this:  while(iterator != NULL) {
 fprintf(fptr, "\nPet Name: %s\nAge: %d\n", iterator->name, iterator->age);
 iterator = iterator->next;
} I still don't have any data in my file though :/

Comment: Works for me :)

Comment: I'll check it out again! Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

After 3 years 7 months, somehow I got this question while solving my problem to write the data of a `linked list` to a `.txt` file. I came here to seek the solution of my problem, but this question hasn't accepted any answers. So here I'll try to answer this question.

> 1. There's no need for global variables in the program.
> 2. Send some arguments to the functions in the program, it'll make your task a lot easier.
> 3. While iterating inside those functions you are losing your `head` structure variable by doing this `petRecord = petRecord->next` and inside main `newRecord = newRecord->next`. This is happening because of the Global variables. So, to avoid this you need to declare each time, inside the called function a `local` pointer variable of type `struct Node`.
> 4. Don't do this: `newRecord->name = malloc(50*sizeof(char));`, if you know the exact size of `char` array instead of doing this, modify your `struct` template to `char name[50]`. It is a lot easier than using a pointer and dynamic allocation because in the latter case you need to take extra care and precaution.
> 5. Open file in which the `data` is to be written inside `main()` function and send it to the function `writeToFile()`.
> 6. Extra care should be taken while dealing with `strings`.
> 7. It is worth checking errors while allocating memory or opening files. So each time when you do any of these in your program, it's better to check for any kinda error that occurred while the operation.

---

Why don't you try this **program:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    char name[50];
    int age;
    struct Node *next;
}Node;

// user-defined functions
void printPetRecord(Node *head);
void writeToFile(FILE *fptr, Node *head);

// main()
int main(void)
{
    int count, i;
    Node *petRecord, *newRecord;
    FILE *fp;

    if( (petRecord = malloc(sizeof(Node))) == NULL )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory.\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    newRecord = petRecord;
    printf("How many pets do you have? ");
    scanf("%d", &count);

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("Name of Pet: ");
        scanf("%50s", newRecord->name);
        printf("Age of Pet: ");
        scanf("%d", &newRecord->age);
        if(i == count-1)
        {
            newRecord->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            if( (newRecord->next = malloc(sizeof(Node))) == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Memory Unavailable.\n");
                exit(3);
            }
        }
        newRecord = newRecord->next;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    // Modified arguments
    printPetRecord(petRecord);

    // Open file before sending to writeToFile
    if(!(fp = fopen("petname.txt", "w")))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file \"petname.txt\"\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // Modified arguments
    writeToFile(fp, petRecord);
    
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

// function to print linked_list
void printPetRecord(Node *head)
{
    if(head->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("Name of Pet: %s\nAge of Pet: %d\n", head->name, head->age);
        printPetRecord(head->next);
    }
    else
        printf("Name of Pet: %s\nAge of Pet: %d\n", head->name, head->age);
}

// function to print list to file
void writeToFile(FILE *fptr, Node *head)
{
    if(head->next != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(fptr, "\nPet Name: %s\nAge: %d\n\n", head->name, head->age);
        writeToFile(fptr, head->next);
    }
    else
        fprintf(fptr, "\nPet Name: %s\nAge: %d\n\n", head->name, head->age);
}
```

**Output(on console):**

```
How many pets do you have? 3
Name of Pet: Tommy
Age of Pet: 3
Name of Pet: Julia
Age of Pet: 4
Name of Pet: Hedgehog
Age of Pet: 5


Name of Pet: Tommy
Age of Pet: 3
Name of Pet: Julia
Age of Pet: 4
Name of Pet: Hedgehog
Age of Pet: 5
```

**Output(inside `petname.txt` file):**

```
Pet Name: Tommy
Age: 3


Pet Name: Julia
Age: 4


Pet Name: Hedgehog
Age: 5
```